# Setting the Background Color of a UITableViewCell to a Pattern Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have the follow code which sets the background of a `UITableViewCell` to a pattern image:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TestPattern"]];
cell.backgroundColor = color;
```

This works and the background pattern is displayed, but the pattern overlaps strangely:

[image]

I think this is because the `UITableViewCell` is actually setting the background color of the labels and other views it contains along with its main view. How can I get the background color to not overlap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think this is because the UITableViewCell is actually setting the background color of the labels

Correct, and very well explained. So you have to set the background color of the labels to `clearColor` separately. This is not entirely easy because, depending on the version of iOS, the runtime will try to set it back again for you; in iOS 4, for example, it was necessary to make this move in `willDisplayCell`, though in iOS 6 you can get away with doing it in `cellForRow` as long as you do it *after* setting the background color.

Comment: Why don't the label's backgrounds default to clear color? Seems like that would make more sense.

Comment: You can't go from "ought" to "is". :( See my full discussion of the problem of setting the `backgroundColor` here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#SECcellstyles

Comment: Do accessory views also get their backgrounds automatically set?